# In redux-form, show all validation errors in Field-Level Validation

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am new in react and am trying to create a form where I show multiple validation errors in each field.

This is the field

```
    <Field
        name="field_name"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        customClass="long-input"
        normalize={normAll([...])}
        validate={[rules.required, rules.another_rule, rules.this_rule]}
    />
```

This is my `renderField`

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, customClass, disabled, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div class={customClass}>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} disabled={disabled} />
      {console.log(error)}
      <div class="error-message">{touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

And here is the Field-Level Validation rules

```
rules.required = value => (value || typeof value === 'number' ? undefined : 'Required')
rules.another_rule = value => (value && value === '3' ? undefined : 'This is not 3')
rules.this_rule = value => (value && value === '5' ? undefined : 'This is not 5')
```

The problem is that if the first rule in the list is not validated, it doesn't show the validation errors for the other rules.

Is there any way to show all of them? As you see, I checked with `console.log(error)` and only the first one is passed in the `renderField`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Field Level validation, but I believe that with Sumbit Validation you could push each error into an array and then map that array in your custom Input component.

I haven't tested it though, I'm just proposing a solution.